# Error seemingly inconsistent behaviour in overloaded operator= used in variable definition

Tags: c++

Why doesn't compile ? Shouldn't it compile ? What do I not understand ? ( using g++ -std=c++1y )

```
struct S{
    int a,b;
    void operator=(int x){a=x;b=x*x;}
};

int main(){
    S s0=S{15,20};
    S s1;s1=5;
    S s2;s2=7;
    S s3=9;
}
```

main.cpp:10:7: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘S’ requested

It seems to me that "S s1;s1=5;" and "S s1=5;" should be equivalent at least that is expected from a naive user! Is there any good reason for that not being true ?

Comment: Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: Care to share the compiler errors? I don't feel like doing your compilers work *again*.

Comment: You need to read more about [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), especially the [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Assignment_operator).

Comment: It's not inconsistent since they don't do the same thing.

Comment: `S s3=9;` this actually calls for the constructor, not for the assignment operator and you don’t have  constructor taking `int`

Answer (score 3):

`S s1 = 5;` and `S s1; s1 = 5;` are not equivalent.

The first one is a declaration that provides initializer `5` for the object `s1` being created. There is no assignment. (The `=` symbol serves different purposes in a declaration than in a statement - as does `&`, `*`, etc.)

The second one declares s1, default-constructing it; and then calls the assignment operator.

`S s1 = 5;` is exactly equivalent to `S s1 { S(5) };` , but the temporary `S(5)` usually undergoes copy elision.