# How to use operator= with a reference

Tags: c++

The code bellow pertains to question [Error seemingly inconsistent behaviour in overloaded operator= used in variable definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506093) that has been answered.
My question arized in the context of trying to define and initialize a reference to a structure using an integer.

So I need instead of writting "S s1=3;" I need to write "S& s1=3;" how am I going to manage it;

```
struct S{
    int a,b;
    void operator=(int x){a=x;b=x*x;}
    S(){};
    S(int x){a=x;b=x*x;}
};

int main(){
    S s1;s1=5;
    S s2;s2=7;
    S s3=9;
    S s4;
}
```

The code of main() should be modifified as follows:

```
int main(){
    //S s0=S{15,20};
    S s1;s1=5;
    S s2;s2=7;
    S s3=9;
    S s4;

    S& s5;s5=10;
    S& s6=10;
}
```

but compiling I have errors:

main.cpp:16:5: error: ‘s5’ declared as reference but not initialized

main.cpp:17:8: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘S&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’ ( regards s6 ).

Comment: `S& s1=3` doesn't really make sense as it would cause dangling of an out-of-scope anonymous temporary.

Comment: `S s1=3;` does not use `operator=`. And your overload should at least return the proper type.

Comment: You can't; a reference to `S` must be initialised to refer to an existing object of type `S`. Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: @MikeSeymour The real problem is that I have an array of S (S A[0x10] ) and by writing S& s6=5 I want to mean S& s6=A[5]; Can I do it ?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: So write `S& s6=A[5];`, if that's what you want to say. There's no way that the number `5` can mean `A[5]`.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis No, you can't. You should probably ask a question about what you're trying to accomplish (i.e. what problem brought you along this path) instead of asking why your solutions don't work.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are not using `operator=`, rather this is a *copy-initialization*.

That is, the expression `S s1 = 3;` uses **non-explicit** constructor `S(int x)` and also **non-explicit** and **accessible** copy constructor `S(const S& x)` (hopefully without any additional overhead).

Going further, you can't use `S& s1 = 3;` not because you *cannot assign 3 to reference*, but because the right hand side of assignment is an R-VALUE (that is, *a temporary*). However, you can extend its lifetime using const reference to l-value, as r-values like very much to be bound by const l-value references:

```
const S& s1 = 3;
```

This will work as long as `S(int x)` is not marked as `explicit`.

Alternatively, (you should not do that at all), you can use r-value reference:

```
S&& s1 = 3; // implicitly
S&& s2 = S(3); // explicitly
```

And the error you see trying to compile `S& s5;`:

```
main.cpp:16:5: error: ‘s5’ declared as reference but not initialized
```

tells you that you cannot just create a variable that is a *reference* (as opposed to pointers), without initializing it.

But if you had a validly initialized reference, then whenever you would use assignment, only then the `operator=` would be invoked:

```
S s1(1);
S& s1ref = s1;
S s2(2);
s1ref = s2; // s1.operator=(s2);
```

Comment: `S s1 = 3;` means `S s1 = S(3);` , so there is "overhead" compared to `S s1(3);`. The temporary may be elided but the class must still have an accessible copy/move constructor

Comment: Here is an [example](http://ideone.com/eie7VS) showing that the copy constructor is required

Comment: that is called *copy elision*. It might be invoked.

Comment: BTW this is also why explicit constructor cannot be called (the temporary object `S(3)` must have implicit constructor called since this object wasn't explicitly initialized)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible; a reference must refer to an object. You can do either of the following (using C++98 syntax):

```
S const &s1 (3);   // same as S const &s1 = S(3);
```

or

```
S s0(3); S &s1(s0);
```