# Reference variable with operator= overload in order to write S& s=5; instead of S& s=A[5];

Tags: c++

The question [How to use operator= with a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506606/how-to-use-operator-with-a-reference) is the base but it has been worded differently.

```
struct S{
    int a,b;
    void operator=(int i);
    S(int i);
    S(){};
};

S A[0x10];

S::S(int i){*this=A[i];}
void S::operator=(int i){*this=A[i];}

int main(){
    //S s0=S{15,20};
    S s1;s1=5;
    S s2;s2=7;
    S s3=9;
    S s4;
//  S& s5=8;   

}
```

Whith the above code I am able to write: `S s=5` instead of `S s=A[5]` now I need the same for references in order to be able to write: `S& s=5;` instead of `S& s=A[5];`

Comment: Use a non-standards-compliant compiler, or pick another language. What you ask for can't be done in standard C++.

Comment: Whyt reason would you have to do such a thing, except confusing others who would read your code? (That includes yourself in a few months)

Comment: How do you expect your overloaded operator to recognise the difference between assigning a value and array element?

Comment: Please look at the changes in the question for clarifications !

Comment: To your edited code: that makes no sense. A reference has to refer to another variable. You can't have an `S& s5` refering to nothing. Maybe you misunderstood something in the concept of references? `S& s = A[5]` means `s` refers to the sixth element of `A`, which *is* another variable.

Comment: But you can `S& s = 5[A];`, just for fun.

Comment: The only way you're going to get this to work the way you want it is to create a language because no sensible language works this way.

Comment: Ok I know that s5 doesn't works, I need s6 to work ! THAT IS THE PROBLEM

Comment: I told you in my first comment that you can't do that. Time to move on.

Comment: `s6` does not refer to anything either, so it does make as little sense as `s5`.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis, You've completely avoided the question of why you can't just type `A[10]` like the rest of us do.

Comment: This is starting to sound like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use a constant reference. That is instead of

```
S& s5;s5=10;
S& s6=10;
```

(by the way this statement

```
S& s5;s5=10;
```

is invalid because a reference shall be initialized in the time of its definition )

you have to write

```
const S& s5 = 10;
const S& s6 = 10;
```

Comment: But it's supposed to refer to `A[10]` or something.

Comment: @chris  I do not underatnd what he means using expression S[5]. At least in his main I do not see a using of this expression.

Comment: *What do I have to do in order to be able to write: S& s=5; instead of S& s=A[5];*

Comment: @chris  See his code example.

Comment: I know. I'm not sure why it doesn't even have an `A`.

Comment: @chris  Thus it is his problem not mine. So it would be more naturally if you would ask the question to him.

Comment: Sorry for a little bit of confusion during the question, I believe now the question is clearer and the code consistent with the question

Comment: @George Kourtis No, it is not clear. For example what does "I am able to write: S s=5 instead of S s=A[5]" mean?

Comment: That means that the code "S s=5" is equivalent in effect to "S s=A[5]"

Comment: @George Kourtis I am sorry i do not understand this. The two constructions are not equivalent.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I may be wrong somewhere but S::S(int i){*this=A[i];} means that during construction using "S s=4" *this is set = to A[i].

Comment: @George Kourtis  It may be done because the globel array A of type S mist be defined before the definition of the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `5` literal for other purpose than just a number, but you can declare your own *user-defined literal*:

```
struct S
{
};

S A[10];

S& operator "" _(unsigned long long int i)
{
    return A[i];
}

int main()
{
    S& s = 5_;
}
```

[Live demo link.](http://ideone.com/B1WKgs)

Comment: I already use them but for different purposes, it's not what I need in the specific case, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`s=5` means *`s` have to have same value as object initialized using `5`.*
`s=A[5]` means *`s` have to have same value as `A`'s sixth element.*

Also, it seems you don't understand references.

Reference (`S&`) is creation referring to variable. While creating it, you have to say to which variable it's pointing to.

`S& s6=10;`
In this case, `10` is *temporary* variable. It's gonna disappear soon. If you want modify it, you should use *reference to temporary* (`S&&`), added in C++11. Alternatively, you can use *const reference* (`const S&`), aviable in previous standards.

Comment: You got a one-off-error there. It's `A`'s sixth element, not the fifth ;-) And `10` is not a temporary variable, it's a literal, a compiletime constant, which is no variable at all.

Comment: For the first part of your comment I think you are missing that the constructor is overloaded and s=5 means S::S(int i){*this=A[i];}.

Comment: Yes. And `A[5]` is the sixth element in `A`. `A[0]` is the first.

Answer (score 0):

What I see as missing is the possibility in C++ to define a constructor for the reference instead for the object it self.

As Vlad from Moscow pointed out the code compiles when the reference is made constant, albeit the result refers to the just constructed new object ( a new S copied from A with index i ).

In order to obtain what needed the compiler should offer the possibility of a reference constructor something like

```
S&(int i){....}
```

But the compiler ( and or the language - I don't know that ) doesn't offer that possibility limiting what can be done overloading a constructor to non references.